# Error in executing dynamically created query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My StoredProcedure is like this

```
    USE [Workcamps]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER   PROCEDURE  [dbo].[ph_TshirtReport]

    @CampCode nvarchar(20) = NULL,
    @strAddtlCriteria VARCHAR(150) = ''
AS

    DECLARE @strSQL VARCHAR(900)

    SET @strSQL = 'select distinct [VolID]  ,[VolFName]  FROM [vTShirtBase] WHERE @CampCode IS NULL OR CampCode=@CampCode'

    IF Len(@strAddtlCriteria) > 0
        SET @strSQL = @strSQL + ' and ' + @strAddtlCriteria

    exec (@strSQL)
```

And I am executing it like this

```
    USE [Workcamps]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[ph_TshirtReport]
        @CampCode = N'14CA11',
        @strAddtlCriteria = N'GroupStaff = 0 And TSWithGS = 0 And StaffAtTraining = 0 And MinJobType <> S And Setup = 0'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Everything looks okay to me. But it throws an error

```
    Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@CampCode".
```

I have no idea why this happens, Can any one point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your SET @strSQL code. Set like this:

```
SET @strSQL = 'select distinct [VolID]  ,[VolFName]  FROM [vTShirtBase] WHERE ' + @CampCode + ' IS NULL OR CampCode=' + @CampCode
```

Comment: @Athul You can try now. I din't notice the variable was being used twice

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[ph_TshirtReport]
@CampCode NVARCHAR(20) = NULL ,
@strAddtlCriteria VARCHAR(150) = ''
AS
DECLARE @strSQL VARCHAR(900)


SET @strSQL = 'Declare @CampCode nvarchar(20) ' + CHAR(13)
SET @strSQL = @strSQL + ' Set  @CampCode = ''' + @CampCode + '''' + CHAR(13)
SET @strSQL = @strSQL + ' select distinct [VolID]  ,[VolFName]  FROM [vTShirtBase] WHERE  @CampCode   IS NULL OR CampCode= ''' + @CampCode + ''''

IF LEN(@strAddtlCriteria) > 0
    SET @strSQL = @strSQL + ' and ' + @strAddtlCriteria
PRINT @strSQL
EXEC (@strSQL)
```